# How to contain video height to <div>?

Tags: html, css, video

How can we keep contained `bucket-list.mp4` in `video-jumbotron`. The video is full-width, but depending on the screen size, the video's height runs off the bottom of the page instead of being cut off and contained in `<div class="video-jumbotron">`, which is the goal of this question.

[image]

**view**

```
<div class="video-jumbotron">
  <video id="bg-video" autoplay="true" loop='true'>
    <source src="/assets/bucket-list.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <%= image_tag 'goal-setting-bucket-list-website.png' %>
  CHALLENGE WHAT YOU DO
  TO CREATE THE LIFE YOU WANT
</div>

# Bottom of video appears underneath this <div>
<div style="background-color: white;">
  Testing
</div>
```

**css**

```
.video-jumbotron {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#bg-video {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: .video-jumbotron {overflow: hidden;} or body {overflow:hidden;} probably for that matter.

Comment: Nope :[ Still overflows at bottom @ChrisW.

Comment: Then there's likely more to it regarding your culprit and more of the layout needs seen. It's cool though, there's tons of folks that scour the simpler html/css questions by the minute and I'm about out of here for the day. Cheers :)

Comment: Yea added more to question. I've controlled for basically everything so I can't imagine what it could be. Thanks for your help anyway @ChrisW. Enjoy the sunshine!

Comment: Set .video-jumbotron to position: relative; + overflow: hidden; and set #bg-video to position: absolute;

Comment: That worked! I tried so many tricks and that did the trick. If you want to add the answer below that would be great otherwise I could answer below @MajeStic

Comment: If this is the answer, we should put it below to help others=) I'm glad it helped. And not to waste the comment only with nonsense - height: 100%; could be added to the video#bg-video so it gets  fully contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the #bg-video (video block) is fixed it will have no relation to your parent div .video-jumbotron and it will be relative (fixed) to the body.

We want to relate the video tag -> #bg-video to it's parent -> .video-jumbotron, so we can contain it.

Add these styles in addition to yours (change #bg-video position from *fixe*d to *absolute*):

```
.video-jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bg-video {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now the parent div .video-jumbotron has control and can teach the child what not to do :)

Comment: A little explanation of your solution would be helpful.